# React useState hook inside useEffect hook does not set state when running unit tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am learning React and am now trying out unit testing. I have login functional component with this following code fragment:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  usersService.getUsers().then((allUsers: User[]) => {
    setUsers(allUsers);
  });
}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

It all works just fine when I run the app. However, when I try to run the test for this, it does not set the users to state. Here is a mock and a test that I wrote:

```
const usersServiceMock: UsersService = {
  getUsers: (): Promise<User[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      process.nextTick(() =>
        resolve([{ username: 'test', password: 'test', imageUrl: '', id: 0 } as User])
      );
    });
  },
} as UsersService;

it('logs user in', async () => {
  const loginSpy = jest.spyOn(loginServiceMock, 'logUserIn');
  const usersSpy = jest.spyOn(usersServiceMock, 'getUsers');

  const component = render(
    <Login loginService={loginServiceMock} usersService={usersServiceMock} />
  );

  expect(usersSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  //up until here, test is fine, but users are not set inside component  
});
```

Mock service is provided properly and mocked user data is properly resolved but setUsers(allUsers) does not actually set it with tests. Inside the effect, usersService.getUsers() does get mocked data but it never sets it.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  usersService.getUsers().then((allUsers: User[]) => {
    // allUsers value is [{ username: 'test', password: 'test', imageUrl: '', id: 0}]        
    setUsers(allUsers);
    // users value is []
  });
}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Here is function that uses the state. It works when running the app, but when running tests, users is still empty array.

```
const login = (): void => {
const userFromDb = users.find((u) => u.username === user.username);
if (!userFromDb || userFromDb.password !== user.password) {
  setUser({
    username: '',
    password: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  });
  setIsDialogOpen(true);
 } else {
  loginService.logUserIn(userFromDb);
  history.push('/home');
 }
};
```

Any ides?

Comment: what do you mean "setUsers(allUsers) does not actually set it"? the value of `users` remains the same in the next render?

Comment: why don't you just mock it like this: `getUsers: () => Promise.resolve([{ username: 'test', password: 'test', imageUrl: '', id: 0 } as User])`

Comment: @MihályiZoltán Yes. I edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Xesenix I tried, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` does not change the local variable (this is impossible in js, especially when using const).
It just ensures that calling the useState in the next render will return the new value.

- If you need the new value where you set it, jus use the same variable (allUsers).
- If you need the new value elsewhere, you will see it in the state variable (users).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need it elsewhere, and it still does not have correct value-it contains initial value of empty array when running tests. When running app, it works fine.

Comment: where is this code? in the same render method as useState? The login function is created every time "render" is called, and each instance "sees" a different `users` variable. Maybe you are referencing the old login function, with the obsolete value?